# How to get the device's scale factor?

Tags: objective-c, ios, uiimage

I've been using `UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions()` and I noticed that the last field in that method is a `scalefactor`. And the apple docs says, if I want to set it to 0.0, then it will use the default scale factor of the device's main screen. Is there a way to get that default scale factor via property or method?

Comment: in the context of images, `UIImage` as a `scale` property, in case you do not want to be tied to the device rather to the content.

Answer (score 117, accepted):

The device's scale factor is a property of `UIScreen`. You can obtain it by:

```
[UIScreen mainScreen].scale;
```

[Documentation here](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIScreen_Class/Reference/UIScreen.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UIScreen/scale).

Comment: For iPhone 6+/7+/8+, you may consider UIScreen.main.nativeScale (Swift code, for iOS 8+) if you want a perfectly aligned to screen pixel.  For example, a one pixel divider or hairline, or 2px on 6/7/8 and 3px on 6+/7+/8+ as if the border of a segmented control.

Answer (score 43):

Swift 3+ version:

```
UIScreen.main.scale
```

Comment: Swift3: `UIScreen.main.scale`

Answer (score 3):

**Swift 5+**

```
let scale = UIScreen.main.scale
print("scale is:\(scale)")
```

Comment: How is this different from the Swift 3+ answer updated 3 years earlier?

Answer (score 3):

Swift5+ / macOS Big Sur:

```
let backingScaleFactor = NSScreen.main?.backingScaleFactor
```

Answer (score -2):

Hope it will help you

```
 CGSize textcontent =CGSizeMake(width, height);
UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(textcontent);
if ([UIScreen instancesRespondToSelector:@selector(scale)] && [[UIScreen mainScreen] scale] == 2.0f)
{
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(textcontent, YES, 1.0f);
}
else
{
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(textcontent);
}
 [view.layer renderInContext:UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()];
 viewImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
 UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
 return viewImage;
```

Comment: `[[UIScreen mainScreen] scale] == 2.0f` is erroneous, don't compare floats using `==`.

Comment: did you import.. #import <QuartzCore/QuartzCore.h>

Comment: what are you talking about?