# iOS: Detecting the actual screen size of iPhone

Tags: ios, iphone, uiscreen

I'm not looking to get a scale of the size of screen. I'm trying to get the actual size of the screen. For iPhone 5. When I try to get the size of the iPhone 5 I get the size of the iPhone 4/4s.

Here is my code:

```
CGRect myScreen=[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds];
```

But the size I get is the following:

```
po myScreen
(origin = (x = 0, y = 0), size = (width = 480, height = 320))
 (origin = (x = 0, y = 0), size = (width = 480, height = 320))
```

But if Use the following line of code:

```
 UIScreen *mainScreen = [UIScreen mainScreen];

po mainScreen
<UIScreen: 0x16d834b0; bounds = {{0, 0}, {480, 320}}; mode = <UIScreenMode: 0x16e68040; size = 640.000000 x 960.000000>>
```

But if I use:

```
po mainScreen.bounds.size
(width = 480, height = 320)
```

My question to you guys is how can I access to the size "size = 640.000000 x 960.000000" using UIScreen.

I really appreciate your help.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to get the devices scale factor?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14018305/how-to-get-the-devices-scale-factor)

Comment: @A-Live  I'm not looking to scale the screen. I want to know the size of the screen

Comment: Notice the that the size you want is from the screen mode of the screen.

Comment: @rmaddy, can you please explain

Comment: @A-Live, I edit my question. As I mention before this is not a duplicate

Comment: Look at the docs for UIScreen and UIScreenMode.

Comment: What's the reason for needing pixels instead of points? Will what you're trying to accomplish handle edge cases like iPad split-screen (or picture-in-picture) multitasking?  Would Adaptive UI and size classes be a better fit?

Comment: Stupid comment, but have you included a LaunchScreen or launch images for 4 inch iPhones in your application? if not the application will be launched in reduced size (3"5 (and have a black border above and bellow it on your iPhone)

Comment: You have options, either use `UIScreenMode` as hinted above or multiply points by scale factor as should be obvious from the hit above too. I'd use scale because I'm not well familiar with `UIScreenMode` and its documentation seems to be incomplete as of now.

Answer (score 0):

Simply use nativeBounds instead of bounds.